# Puma Won't Restart With A SIGUSR1 signal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, sinatra, puma

I have a simple sinatra app that I am serving using puma on jruby behind nginx.

I've got my sample application up and running and working fine.

I am now trying to manually restart the puma server by sending the SIGUSR1 signal, as described in [the puma docs](https://github.com/puma/puma).  However, instead of causing the server to restart, I start getting 502 bad gateway error.  The nginx logs show:

```
013/10/17 20:40:12 [error] 755#0: *25 connect() to unix:///var/run/mysockets/te 
st_app.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, clien 
t: <my ip>, server: jonahtest.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstr 
eam: "http://unix:///var/run/mysockets/test_app.sock:/", host: "jonahtest.example 
.com"
```

So instead of restarting, it stops working.  Here is how I issued the SIGUSR1 signal:

```
deploy@server:/var/www/webricktest$ jobs -p
863
deploy@server:/var/www/webricktest$ kill -s SIGUSR1 863
deploy@server:/var/www/webricktest$ jobs -p
863
[1]+  User defined signal 1   puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/mysockets/test_app.sock
deploy@server:/var/www/webricktest$
```

and shortly thereafter, on their own, both the original puma process and the and the user defined signal vanish, and if I run `jobs -p` again I get nothing.  However, the socket remains at /var/run/mysockets/test_app.sock, and I have to manually `rm` it in order to restart puma again.

My question is: Why is `kill -s SIGUSR1 <pid>` not working to restart puma?  How can I make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple error on my part, caused by reading some out of date tutorials.

You simply need to send the `SIGUSR2` signal and not the `SIGUSR1`